# How to avoid re-render of children components

Tags: reactjs

I have a rendering problem that I can't fix.
On my application, I have a `Posts` component that has a state containing an array of posts data.

```
[
  { id: "P01", title: "First post", likeCount: 0 },
  { id: "P02", title: "Second post", likeCount: 0 }
]
```

In this component, I map the `posts` state to return a `Post` component for each post inside the posts state.

Posts component

```
export default function Posts() {
  const [posts, setPosts] = useState(null);

  const fetchPosts = () => {
    setPosts([
      { id: "P01", title: "First post", likeCount: 0 },
      { id: "P02", title: "Second post", likeCount: 0 }
    ]);
  };

  const handleLike = (id) => {
    setPosts(
      posts.map((post) =>
        post.id === id ? { ...post, likeCount: post.likeCount + 1 } : post
      )
    );
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={fetchPosts}>Fetch posts</button>
      {posts !== null ? (
        posts.map((post, index) => {
          return <Post key={index} post={post} handleLike={handleLike} />;
        })
      ) : (
        <p>No post to dipslay</p>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Post component

```
function Post({ post, handleLike }) {
  console.count("Renders for: " + post.id);
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{post.title}</h1>
      <p>Like count: {post.likeCount}</p>
      <button onClick={() => handleLike(post.id)}>Like</button>
    </div>
  );
}


export default React.memo(Post);
```

The problem is that, whenever I like a `Post`, all the other `Post` components re-render.
I added a `console.count()` on the children component `Post` to show this in action (see below for the sandbox link).
Because of that, I have a performance issue because, on my appplication, I have a lot of posts to display with a lot of children components.

I tried to wrap the `Post` component using `React.memo` but it is still re-rendering the component because the `handleLike` function passed as props to the component also changed when `Posts` re-rendered.
Maybe it is possible to avoid this rendering problem using the `useMemo / useCallback` hooks, but I'm not familiar with those and i can't get them to work as I want to.

What are my options here?

You can find a simplified demo code here: https://codesandbox.io/s/re-render-issue-esm01

Comment: Working sandbox example - https://codesandbox.io/s/re-render-issue-vfdil

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would like to highlight the below points before anything else

> When a component’s **props or state change**, React decides whether an actual DOM update is necessary by comparing the newly returned element with the previously rendered one. **When they are not equal, React will update the DOM.**

> Even though **React only updates the changed DOM nodes**, re-rendering still takes some time. In many cases it’s not a problem, but if the slowdown is noticeable, you can speed all of this up by overriding the `lifecycle` function `shouldComponentUpdate` (`React.memo` if you are using **function component**)

Coming to your example, I have inspected the DOM and observed that only the respective `like count` is updating in **actual DOM**.

[image: DOM update]

To combat with performance issue (noticeable slowdown in re-rendering), you can use approach suggested in [Jayshree Wagh's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63303579/13907595) as below

```js
// Posts.js
const handleLike = useCallback(id => {
  setPosts(posts => posts.map(
      post => post.id === id ? ({ ...post, likeCount: post.likeCount + 1 }) : post
    )
  );
}, []);

// Post.js
export default React.memo(Post, (prevProps, nextProps) => prevProps.post === nextProps.post);
```

See the [good example for useCallback](https://dmitripavlutin.com/dont-overuse-react-usecallback).

Avoid using `index` as `key` in case you are using it in actual code.

Answer (score 4):

Never use indexes as key as per react's [official document](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html). Use of index as key in react component lead you to unwanted re-rendering.

Let me explain in brief. A key is the only thing React uses to identify DOM elements. What happens if you push an item to the list or remove something in the middle? It will change all the keys of other component as well and re-render them.

For improving more you can use React.memo and React.useCallback. You can find more details in [this link](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html)

Comment: Hi, I made a mistake on the demo code, I actually never use the index as the key, but it's a good point!

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this

```
const Post = React.memo(
  props => {...},
 (prevProps, nextProps) => prevProps.post === nextProps.post
);
```

when the function returns true, the component will not be re-rendered

Comment: Hi, I'm not sure how I can implement that

Comment: In your case 
Instead of this `export default React.memo(Post);`  do something like this`export default memo(Post, (prevState, nextState) => prevState.post === nextState.post) ;`

Answer (score 0):

Your handlers are recomputed on each render, making `React.memo(Post)` useless.

Please use `useCallback` hook
https://en.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback

Comment: This is what I noticed too, but I can't find a good way to implement the callback on the handleLike function. If I pass an empty dependency array, it won't work because the posts state will change after I fetch the posts data, and if I pass a [posts] dependency array, then it won't work either because it will be recomputed everytime I like a post and I will face the same problem.

Comment: but why do you think it won't work either. only liked post will be updated even whole array changed reference. Try to debug with https://github.com/welldone-software/why-did-you-render

Comment: Maybe it's the way I am modifying the array that recomputes the handleLike function everytime? 
I tried like this

const handleLike = useCallback(
    (id) => {
      setPosts(
        posts.map((post) =>
          post.id === id ? { ...post, likeCount: post.likeCount + 1 } : post
        )
      );
    },
    [posts] // using [] or [setPosts], the app crashes => Cannot read property 'map' of null
  );

And using the react profiler tool, it says the all the Post components re-rendered because the prop handleLike has changed
Maybe I am doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You should be using `useCallback` on your `handleLike` handler. The state setter should then be using a callback instead of a dependable value, like this:

```js
const handleLike = useCallback((id) => {
  setPosts(
    posts=>{
      return posts && posts.map((post) =>
        post.id === id ? { ...post, likeCount: post.likeCount + 1 } : post,
      )
    },
  );
},[setPosts]);
```

Comment: It doesn't work: "Cannot read property 'map' of null". I think it's because the useCallback has a reference to the posts state initialized with a null value.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know how to do it with React Hook but you can transform Post component from functional component to class component, then use `shouldComponentUpdate()` to choose what make your component re-render.

Comment: I want to avoid using class component because I am not familiar with those.

Answer (score -1):

I would add something like InitializeApp in a global state and an ActionCreator that you can call on your component, or you can use React.memo "https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo".

Comment: You should include an example how this will solve the problem and try to limit use of adding URL's to look up.